# How to access django python returned JSON data in the javascript part of an htmlpage

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to know how to access the a django python returned JSON data in the javascript part of an html page. This is JSON data that I'm getting from the server end which I've logged in the browser console

**{"movieName": "Avengers", "releaseYear": "2019", "boxOffice": "2.3B"}**

**68**

Here is my sample code

Javascript part

```
var dataFromDjango = "{{ myData | escapejs | safe }}";
console.log(dataFromDjango);
var t = Object.keys(dataFromDjango).length;
console.log(t);
```

Python code

```
context = {}
context['movieName'] = 'Avengers'
context['releaseYear'] = str(2019)
context['boxOffice'] = '2.3B'

jsonData = json.dumps(context)
return render(request, "InterfacePage.html", {"myData" : jsonData})
```

I was expecting the length of keys to be 3.

Comment: You here injected it as a string, not as a json blob. You should write this like `var dataFromDjango = {{myData | escapejs | safe}};` so *without* the quotes.

Comment: I get this error if I omit the quotes "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: ah sorry, you need to remove the `escapejs` as well, or probably more safe, use `json.parse` at the receiving end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse it from a JSON string to a JS object. Note, you shouldn't use `escapejs` here.

```
var dataFromDjango = JSON.parse("{{ myData | safe }}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You here present your JSON blob as a string. Indeed, you write something like:

```
"{\"movieName\": \"Avengers\", \"releaseYear\": \"2019\", \"boxOffice\": \"2.3B\"}";
```

in your JavaScript file. The `Object.keys(dataFromDjango) will return the indices of the string, so an array from`0`to`68`.

You can present the JSON blob to JavaScript with:

```
var dataFromDjango = JSON.parse('{{ myData | safe }}');
```

so here we let JavaScript conver the string back into a JavaScript object, this is probably the safest option since if the string contains prombe,s then JavaScript will error on the parsing of the JSON blob.